# Getting "Generate serialization assembly" to work

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, xml-serialization

I am in charge of a desktop WPF application, using a few web services (via `Service References` of the project).

Due to a `Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was \"C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727\\csc.exe\" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Ustawienia lokalne\Temp\btucqeci.cmdline"` error on a client's machine  (which I understand is caused by `csc` trying to compile objects for the webservice request on the fly, and failing due to insufficient permissions), I hoped I could use a solution that I came across somewhere and enable the `Generate serialization assembly` option in the `Build / Properties` tab of my project.

It won't build, though - I keep on getting a compile error `Could not find file 'E:\xxxx\xxxx\obj\Debug\xxxx.XmlSerializers.dll`. Well I know it's not there, creating this DLL is precisely what I'm trying to achieve.

All the code for communicating with web-services is auto-generated and I haven't modified it at all.

I tried using `sgen` to achieve the same result "manually", but with no luck: I'm getting `Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`

Could you point me in right direction? If additional information is needed, I will supply it. It's the first time I ran into this type of issue, so I'm a bit in the dark.

By the way, I have a (remote) access to the client's computer, but I failed to resolve the problem by resetting permissions. They run the program on an admin account and permissions do not seem to restricted in any way (based on what I googled up, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310745/creating-xmlserializer-in-net-throws-exception), I suspected the infamous IIS lockdown effect).